# HTML : how to change form action to a class button

Tags: html

let say i want to change from this

```html
<form action="http://10.50.16.108:8080/elgweb/reject">
  <input type="hidden" name="requestId" value="84adc848c748ba94ac95770b31d4f128a36e267a060643bb3ccc5f61d2feb460-1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="requestDateTime" value="2563-01-15 17.45" />
  <input style="font-size:20px;" type="submit" value="No Approve" />
</form>
```

to this

```html
<a class="btn btn-success" href=.http://10.50.16.108:8080/elgweb/reject + requestId + requestDateTime " target="_new ">No Approve</a>
```

is it possible

Comment: you already did .

Comment: Try it out.  Do they both give you the same outcome?

Comment: the button doesnt provide any outcome tho

Comment: Maybe your forgot the `?`. `http://10.50.16.108:8080/elgweb/reject? + requestId + requestDateTime`

Answer (score 0):

If the backend code is accepting GET method you can do it like:

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="http://10.50.16.108:8080/elgweb/reject?requestId=84adc848c748ba94ac95770b31d4f128a36e267a060643bb3ccc5f61d2feb460&requestDateTime=2563-01-15 17.45" target="_new">No Approve</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

let say i want to send an email via smtp relay with this code

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib


fromaddr = "personal@hotmail.com"
toaddr = "system@mydomain.co.th"


html = open("gsxxxb2.html",encoding="utf-8")
msg = MIME(html.read(), 'html')
msg.get
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddr
msg['Subject'] = "Automatic Weekly Report"


debug = False
if debug:
   print(msg.as_string())
else:
   server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.mydomain.com',587)
   server.starttls()
   server.login("system@mydomain", "password")
   text = msg.as_string()
   server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
   server.quit()
```

and i want to substitue requestId + requestDateTime with some values